# Have an issue using datePicker in the release apk

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

Hello guys can u help me with this issue that i'm facing in the release apk
I'm using datePicker widget to show dates in my app it works fine in the debug apk but when i try the release apk sometimes the container appears empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcFb4.jpg)

This the code to show the datePicker widget

```
_addDateBar() {

    return Container(

      margin: EdgeInsets.only(

        top: 2.4.h,

        left: 5.6.w,

      ),

      child: DatePicker(

        height: 12.6.h,

        DateTime.now(),

        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,

        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),

        selectionColor: primaryClr,

        dateTextStyle: TextStyle(

            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 16.sp, color: Colors.grey),

        dayTextStyle: TextStyle(

            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 12.sp, color: Colors.grey),

        monthTextStyle: TextStyle(

            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 12.sp, color: Colors.grey),

        onDateChange: (date) {

          setState(() {

            _selectedDate = date;

          });

        },

      ),

    );

  }
```

Comment: You don't have any error or warning in debug?

Comment: No i don't have any errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this issue by just setting the fontSize to simple double without using .sp in all the texts used in the DatePicker